# Reading XML file as an object in PHP and iterating through content

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read the keys and values in an XML file which I first created as an object and then tried to iterate in a foreach loop. 
My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">10</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">*:*</str><str name="facet.field">main</str><str name="facet.mincount">1</str><str name="rows">0</str><str name="facet">on</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="5473" start="0"/><lst name="facet_counts"><lst name="facet_queries"/><lst name="facet_fields"><lst name="main"><int name="Victoria University Photograph Collection">1693</int>
```

......

My php code is:

```
foreach($input as $int){
    echo $int->response->int;
    $arr = array();

   foreach ($int as $key => $value){
        $arr[(string)$key]=(string)$value;
   }
   $arr[]=$arr;
}
print_r($arr);
```

The echo line does not print anything and the array only prints the xml content that does not have any value. So it only prints [lst]. I need to retrieve the name and value within the  tag.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you turning your XML document into `$input`? Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: $input = simplexml_load_file('collections.xml');

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) expression to get the name and the value of the `int` elements inside the `lst` element.

If you want to put those in an array using the name as the key you might use a multidimensional array where the key value is in it's own array because when the names are the same in the xml the keys using a single dimensional array will be overwritten.

```
$items = $input->xpath('/response/lst/int');
$arr = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($item->attributes()->name) && trim((string)$item) !== "") {
        $arr[] = [(string)$item->attributes()->name => (string)$item];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/V0X8H)

Or to get all the names and values inside the `int` tag:

```
$items = $input->xpath('/response/lst//*');
$arr = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($item->attributes()->name) && trim((string)$item) !== "") {
        $arr[] = [(string)$item->attributes()->name => (string)$item];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SvgKK)

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, I am having trouble formatting the result. The result looks like:
 'Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [QTime] => 10
                )

        )' - And I need the result to be stored in one Array ("status" => 0 .... etc).

Comment: @Krutheeka That is what I mentioned in my answer. I have done it this way because if you have multiple `status` keys they will be overwritten. So `"status" => 0` will become `"status" => 1` etc..

Comment: I had to change my conversion from xml to php as:   $input=file_get_contents('collections.xml'); 
How would i parse through the data now?

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHP manual for SimpleXML:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Also, you XML is poorly formatted, you are using the same element name for different values.  The element name should specify what the value is.

Comment: This is the XML file that was assigned to me, I unfortunately don't have the power to change the content of the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your XML for readability (the content is unmodified). It looks like you only posted a part of your XML in your question, since you're missing a few closing `</lst>` tags at the end and you're missing a closing `</response>` as well:

```
$xml = '
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
        <lst name="responseHeader">
            <int name="status">0</int>
            <int name="QTime">10</int>
            <lst name="params">
                <str name="q">*:*</str>
                <str name="facet.field">main</str>
                <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
                <str name="rows">0</str>
                <str name="facet">on</str>
            </lst>
        </lst>
        <result name="response" numFound="5473" start="0"/>
        <lst name="facet_counts">
            <lst name="facet_queries"/>
            <lst name="facet_fields">
                <lst name="main">
                    <int name="Victoria University Photograph Collection">1693</int>
                </lst>' /* added by me */ . '
            </lst>' /* added by me */ . '
        </lst>' /* added by me */ . '
    </response>' /* added by me */ . '
';

$input = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

SimpleXML will return a reference to the root element, in your case `<response>`. As you can see, in your example code this `<response>` element contains two `<lst>` children and one `<result>` child. This means `$input->lst` will be an array containing two entries: the two `<lst>` elements in the order in which they appear in your document.

Your code is specifically looking for `<int>` elements as a first child of something, which only appears to be the case for the first `<lst>` element. There's another one in the second `<lst>` element, but that one's hidden away at a depper level so I'll skip it for now. So basically, we need to look for `<int>`s in `$input->lst[0]`.

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($input->lst[0]->int as $int) {
    // get the name from the attributes
    $name = (string)$int['name'];

    // get the element's text content
    $value = (string)$int;

    $arr[$name] = $value;
}

print_r($arr);
```

If you want to search through all (top-level) `<lst>` you will need an extra loop:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($input->lst as $lst) {
    foreach ($lst->int as $int) {
        $name = (string)$int['name'];
        $value = (string)$int;

        $arr[$name] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

With your example code, both cases output the following array (since the `<int>` in the second `<lst>` is buried a little deeper):

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [QTime] => 10
)
```

Now, if you want to look through any nested `<lst>` no matter how deep, you might want to consider making a recursive function out of it:

```
function parseLst($lst, &$arr) {
    // note the & before $arr, this is necessary to make `$arr[$name] = $value;` work.
    // Another option would be to use `global $arr;` and not pass it as an argument,
    // or if you're doing this in a class, to use `$this->arr` instead.

    foreach ($lst->int as $int) {
        $name = (string)$int['name'];
        $value = (string)$int;

        $arr[$name] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($lst->lst as $childLst) {
        parseLst($childLst, $arr);
    }
};

$arr = array();

foreach ($input->lst as $lst) {
    parseLst($lst, $arr);
}

print_r($arr);
```

This will yield:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [QTime] => 10
    [Victoria University Photograph Collection] => 1693
)
```